solution-verification | Calculate the distances from A to DC and from B to the plane $(ADC)$.
The problem
Let the non-coplanar points $A,B,C,D$ for which $D'A=BD=DC=8$ cm, $\angle ADB= 60$, $DB\perp DC$ and $(ADC) \perp (ABC) $. Calculate the distances from A to DC and B to the plane $(ADC)$.
my idea
drawing

We can easily calculate $AB=8$ cm and $BC=8\sqrt{2}$
I let $DO\perp (ABC)$
Because in pyramid $DABC$, $AD=DB=DC$ it means that $O$ is the centre of the circumscribed circle of triangle ABC.
I let $DX\perp AC$ and because we also know that $(ADC) \perp (ABC), (ADC)\cap (ABC)=AC$ we get to know that $DX \perp (ABC)$
$DX \perp (ABC), DO \perp (ABC)=> X=O$
we know that $DX\perp AC$ in triangle ADC with $AD=DC=> X$ is the midpoint of AC $=> O$ is the midpoint of AC and O is the center of the circumscribed circle of triangle ABC=> traingle ABC is right angled with $\angle ABC=90$.
By the theorem of Pythagoras we find $AC=8\sqrt{3}$
As you can see in the little drawing I drew beside we have $\angle ADC=120$
From here we can express the area of the triangle DAC in 2 ways and get that $d(A, DC)=4\sqrt{3}$
For the other distance I let $BY\perp AC$ and because $(ADC) \perp (ABC), (ADC)\cap (ABC)=AC$ we get to know that $BY \perp (ADC)$
$BY=\frac{AB*BC}{AC}=\frac{8 \sqrt{6}}{3}$
I put this as an solution-verification, because I'm not sure if this part is right: ,,Because in pyramid $DABC$, $AD=DB=DC$ it means that $O$ is the center of the circumscribed circle of triangle ABC."
Hope one of you can help! Thank you!

The solution looks fine. It should be immediately obvious that $X=O$, as we know that planes $(ADC)$ and $ABC$ are perpedicular, so you could shorten that part of the proof.
